# a surprising (?) behaviour of GNU Make when using ``%`` as target

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile

```
foo:
    @echo '$@'

test:
    @echo '$@'
    @echo '---'

# Catch-all target
%: test
    @echo '+++'
    @echo '$@'
```

When issuing `make bar` the following is the console output:

```
$ make bar
test
---
+++
Makefile
+++
bar
```

I would like to understand the origin of `Makefile` which shows it is received as argument at some point, and also how to get rid of it in such a scheme. This is using

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make treats the makefile itself as a target that needs to be updated. See [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles):

> ... after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it (see Using Implicit Rules), it will be updated if necessary...
>
> If you know that one or more of your makefiles cannot be remade and you want to keep make from performing an implicit rule search on them, perhaps for efficiency reasons, you can use any normal method of preventing implicit rule look-up to do so. For example, you can write an explicit rule with the makefile as the target, and an empty recipe (see Using Empty Recipes).

Hence, the catch-all-target `%` is used to update Makefile.

Makefiles often do not have to be updated, so it is customary to add an empty rule for that:

```
Makefile : ;
```

Comment: `IIRC, it must come before that catch-all-target` This shouldn't be necessary, match-anything rules are only considered when no other rule matches.