# Default Makefile for Sphinx

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx

I'm trying to understand the Makefile that is automatically produced by `sphinx-quickstart`. Here it is:

```
SPHINXOPTS    =
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
SPHINXPROJ    = myproj
SOURCEDIR     = source
BUILDDIR      = build

.PHONY: help Makefile

%: Makefile
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

The lines that confuse me are:

```
.PHONY: help Makefile
%: Makefile
```

### I think I understand:

1. The `%` target means capture anything (wildcard). E.g., if I typed `make html`, `%` would capture `html`.
2. `.PHONY Makefile` means that `make` shouldn't look for a file called `Makefile` in its directory, thus, shouldn't check the file's modified time to determine whether or not to run a rule.

### I don't understand:

Why `Makefile` is listed as a prerequisite for the target `%`. The way I interpret this is:

*The target rule captured by `%` should run when the `Makefile` is changed.*

But that doesn't make any sense in the context. What I would expect is:

*The target rule captured by `%` should run when the source files for the project documentation or the API source files have changed.*

### Directory structure

```
.
├── build
├── Makefile
├── source
└── utils
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.PHONY: foo` has the effect that `foo` is never to be considered up-to-date. (but see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html for the more detailed explanations: the main use is for targets which are not filenames)

If you then have `bar: foo`, the rules for `bar` target will always be executed on `make bar` because the target depends upon `foo` but `foo` is considered never up-to-date. This can also be achieved with declaring `bar` target to be PHONY itself.

The problem with the catch-all `%` target was in case the repertory where the Makefile is located contained a repertory or a file having same name as a Sphinx builder. Say for example there is an `html` or a `man` in repertory where Makefile is located: then `make html` will not do anything if `%` has no dependencies, because `html` is then a file or repertory with no dependencies, hence never to get updated.

Thus the `%` was made to depend on Makefile pseudo target, and Makefile itself declared PHONY so that it is considered never up-to-date.(*) Even if repertory contains a file `html` then `make html` will get executed (and `html` repertory in build dir modified; the `html` in Makefile repertory will not be modified).

(*) edit: I had forgotten the exact details: Makefile is always considered a target, see [a surprising (?) behaviour of GNU Make when using ``%`` as target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062551/a-surprising-behaviour-of-gnu-make-when-using-as-target/40062635#40062635). For reasons explained here `%` was made to depend upon Makefile, and the Makefile was declared PHONY in fact to avoid make complaining about circular dependency...

The idea is that the Makefile should not contain the hard-coded list of all possible builders: else they could have been declared PHONY targets individually, but then Sphinx maintainers would have to worry about keeping the Makefile template up-to-date when adding a new builder. It would also cause problems when projects keep same Makefile but a new Sphinx release adds a new builder.

The Makefile now created by sphinx-quickstart does not have to be modified if a new builder is added to Sphinx. It is of course certain that never will `Makefile` be the name of a builder...

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, it was very useful. I'd like to add that "Makefile is always considered a target" happens just because the file itself is named 'Makefile'. If you rename it to e.g. 'Makefile.test' and run 'make -f Makefile.test', then the target will be indeed "Makefile.test". This is important to keep in mind if using catch-all targets such as in the Sphinx's default Makefile. In my case we were doing this in CI. Solved it by changing the target name to "Makefile*".